# Junit test not working for sumoverarray method Java

Tags: java

I am trying to run a test for my `sumoverarray` method but I keep getting a failure saying AssertionError. Here's my method.

```
public class SumOverArray {

    public static int IterateAndSum(int[] arr) {
        int sum=0;
        for (int i:arr) {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        return sum;
        
    }
}
```

Here is my junit test

```
@Test
    public void test3() {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        assertNotEquals(0, SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(arr));
        try {
            SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(null);
            assertTrue(true);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            fail();
        }
        int [] arr2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
        assertEquals(78, SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(arr2));
        int[] arr3 = { -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9 };
        assertEquals(-45, SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(arr3));
        int[] arr4 = { 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80 };
        assertEquals(1095, SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(arr4));

    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, post the stack trace and highlight the line throwing the `Exception`. I would assume that the first test (the `catch`-block) throws the exception (i.e., that the method throws a `NullPointerException` if `nulll` is passed as an argument to method `IterateAndSum(...)`). --- A test shoudl test one thing and one thing only. Those whould be really three separate tests. --- Method names in Java should always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: You are passing the `null` into `IterateAndSum()`, and making the execution flow to go into `catch{..}`, where you explicitly `fail();`. That's what it is supposed to be doing in your code. Besides, yes, as @Turing85 says, you're having plenty of load in your test method, which is not clean and very much discouraged to practice in Unit Testing.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is expected. Looking at the second part of the test method:

```
try {
    SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(null);
    assertTrue(true);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    fail();
}
```

We call `SumOverArray.IterateAndSum` with `null` and expect no `NullPointerException` to be thrown. But looking at the implementation, we do not perform a `null`-check in method `SumOverArray.IterateAndSum` and thus try to iterate over `null`. This, ultimately, leads to a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. The `catch`-block in the test is entered and the test fails.

All other tests would pass, if this test would pass.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/OlCgqd)

If we, however, want to assert that a `NullPointerException` is thrown when `null` is passed as parameter, then we can use [`Assertions.assertThrows(...)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-):

```
final NullPointerException exception = assertThrows(
    NullPointerException.class,
    () -> SumOverArray.IterateAndSum(null));
// validate exception here if necessary
```

---

Some remarks on the code:

- Method names in Java should always start with a lowercase letter (`IterateAndSum` -> `iterateAndSum`)
- A test should test one thing and one thing only. Thus, the one test method above should be written as four tests.
- The last three tests are redundant, one of them is sufficient.
- The explicit `fail()` on an exception is superfluous and can be omitted.
- Semantically, the first test is also covered by the last three tests. Thus this test is also redundant.
- I would suggest to define a value to return if `null` is passed as argument, `0` seems sensible.

This leaves us with the following two tests:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("should return 0 if null is passed as argument")
public void shouldReturnZerofNullIsPassedAsParameter() {
    // GIVEN: nothing

    // WHEN
    final int actual = SumOverArray.iterateAndSum(null);

    // THEN
    assertEquals(0, actual);
}

// Alternative test, if we want to assure that a NPE is thrown if null is passed
@Test
@DisplayName("should throw NPE if null is passed as argument")
public void shouldThrowNullPointerExceptionIfNullIsPassedAsParameter() {
    // GIVEN: nothing

    // WHEN & THEN
    assertThrows(
        NullPointerException.class,
        () -> SumOverArray.iterateAndSum(null));
}

@Test
@DisplayName("should return 78 if 1, 2 , ... , 12 are summed")
void shouldReturnCorrectResult() {
    // GIVEN
    final int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

    // WHEN
    final int actual = SumOverArray.iterateAndSum(arr);

    // THEN
    assertEquals(78, actual);
}
```